# Сборка golang-части перед сборкой самого Android-приложения

Tags: android, golang, gradle

Возможно ли билдить golang-часть моего приложения из подмодуля git, потому запихивать бинарник в специальную директорию, а далее уже билдить само Android-приложение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если приложение билдится при помощи Gradle, то можно оформить [билд Go части через проект на Maven](https://github.com/raydac/mvn-golang) и сначала билдить его при помощи плагина типа gradle-maven-exec-plugin и потом использовать сгенерированный артифакт